# Web based application with ms access

Tags: ms-access, web

I am currently working with a company where I am not allowed to install software like Sql server or other data base software but I have ms access or office kind software so
my question is

1> Can we create web based application using ms access and .net based programming language.
   (Just to maintain manual based work)

This question might sounds like crazy but I search for it all over internet.Help me

I need to start from beginning...

Comment: yes ofcourse.You can use ms access for database. I have done a web project using java and ms-access.Access query is almost same to mysql with slight difference here and there.

Comment: Yes. You might have difficulty finding examples. If you want to build a web app you are going to have to install visual studio. If anyone is going to use it you are going to have to install IIS. So you have a few hurdles to overcome.

Answer (score 1):

[Connect to MS Access Db](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ybdbtte(v=vs.90).aspx)

[OleDb connection](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-oledb-connection.htm) You will use this when reading/writing to the database. It will need to be opened an closed if you're not using an `IDisposable` method.

[Inserting Records to an MS Access Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586441/adding-data-in-the-database-using-microsoft-access-and-oledb-in-c-sharp)

[Using SQL with c#.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx)

I'm not sure what language you'll be using, but there are actually plenty of examples using VB/C#.NET.